# "Segoe UI Light" font does not render in FireFox 7

Tags: css, fonts

In our website "Segoe UI Light" font does not render properly in FireFox 7, while it does in IE9. What should I check?

Comment: What format is the font? TTF? OTF?

Comment: You should provide an example page.

Comment: Clear the Firefox cache and force a reload.

Comment: @Diodeus: On stock Windows it's a TTF.

Comment: [Here is](http://www.devdept.com) the sample page. The main title is "Segoe UI Light", use FireBug to inspect.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
font-family: Segoe UI;
font-weight: lighter;
```

Actually font family name is Segoe UI and Light is the style (sub font, as in case of bold and italic)

This works on my side

Comment: You'll need to quote the family name: `'Segoe UI'`

Comment: You will need to do this for Chrome as well (and probably Safari too).

Answer (score 14):

This worked perfect for me. Also works on all major browsers.

```
font-family: "Segoe UI Light","Segoe WPC","Segoe UI",
              Helvetica, Arial, "Arial Unicode MS", Sans-Serif;
```

Btw, Segoe UI Light is a standalone font, not a style.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a late answer but I actually just copied what the Microsoft site did, it works great in all the major browsers and most of the non-major.

```
font-family: "wf_SegoeUILight","wf_SegoeUI","Segoe UI Light","Segoe WP Light","Segoe UI","Segoe","Segoe WP","Tahoma","Verdana","Arial","sans-serif";
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user has it installed on their machine. Are you using @font-face?

Comment: Segoe UI is a default font on Windows Vista and newer, the only OSes supported by IE9.

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family: Segoe UI;
font-weight: 300;
```

Font weight at 300 gets it really close to Segoe UI Light.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to get this working in Firefox. Font weight 300 doesnt work few time in all versions. The below code worked for me and compatible with all browsers

```
 font-family: "Segoe UI Light","Segoe UI";
 font-weight: 300;
```